# Facebook Login Fragment Intent to new activity Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, android-intent

I am new in Java and i want to switch Activity after login with the facebook login and switch to the navigation activity after login.

```
public class LoginActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView text_details;

private CallbackManager mCallBackManager;
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
        if (profile != null) {
            text_details.setText(profile.getFirstName());
            //mTextDetails.setText("Welcome " + profile.getName());
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        text_details.setText("ON CANCEL");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        text_details.setText("BIG ERROR EXCEPTION" + e);
    }
};
public LoginActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mCallBackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    text_details = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text_details);
    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setFragment(this);
    loginButton.registerCallback(mCallBackManager, mCallback);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mCallBackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),MainActivity.class);
    getActivity().startActivity(i);
}
```

I want to switch to my main activity, navigation drawer after login with facebook.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
    implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Thx for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onSuccess` callback start `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
    if (profile != null) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityFragment.this.getActivity(), MainActivity.class);  
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have try, but i have a error of compilation:    Error:(40, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>>,Class<MainActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual argument <anonymous FacebookCallback<LoginResult>> cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) ....

Comment: no problem but i have always try, and i have Error:(40, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(LoginActivityFragment,Class<MainActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(actual argument LoginActivityFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(actual argument LoginActivityFragment cannot be converted to String ...

Comment: Try it now I thought it was a fragment not an activity ha.

Comment: Error:(40, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(LoginActivityFragment,Class<MainActivity>) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri,Context,Class<?>) is not applicable (actual and formal argument lists differ in length) constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable (actual argument LoginActivityFragment cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion) constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable (actual argument LoginActivityFragment cannot be converted to String ...

Comment: I have try with you last update, but no its compile but my application crash

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305) at android .app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)

Comment: There's a different problem with your xml file file. Upload that.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="fr.dreamforall.troc31.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Fragment Navigation Drawer:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc" tools:context="myapp.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Activity main

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="myapp.MainActivity">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" android:name="myapp.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```